# Wordpress pagination broken for page 2,3 with custom permalink. Redirects to baseurl

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination, htaccess

I have a forum installed with my Wordpress site. My pagination does not work and redirects pages 2,3, or more to baseurl when they are on homepage. Here are the settings:

```
Forum baseurl: https://example.com/forum
Permalink structure: https://example.com/forum/%category%/%postname%/

Question link: https://example.com/forum/question/how-to-do-xyz/   (Works)
Author link: https://example.com/forum/member/johndoe/             (Works)
Category link: https://example.com/forum/qc/business/              (Works)
CategoryPosts page2: https://example.com/forum/qc/business/page/2/ (Works)
Tag Posts page2: https://example.com/forum/qa-tag/pakistan/page/2/ (Works)
```

HomePage questions Pagination looks like this,

```
https://example.com/forum/?page=2
```

and redirects back to

```
https://example.com/forum
```

For pagination on category and tag pages, it looks correct (https://example.com/forum/business/page/xxx/ & https://example.com/forum/qc-tag/business/page/xxx/)

Here is the `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forum/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: @MrWhite its at the root location of this forum i.e. public_html/example.com/forum

Comment: In your [cross-site post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367616/mod-rewrite-rule-for-pagiantion) you state that, "whereas it should show and also go to `http://example.com/subsite/page/2` which works (if i try manually)" - this is important information missing from your question here. (This makes it an issue that needs to be fixed in WordPress/plugin/theme/forum, nothing to do with `.htaccess`.)